# how to display single product do_action in shop Page in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Is there any method available to display single product **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action woocommerce shop page

Comment: No this is not possible as you will kill your shop and archives pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are a couple ways to do this, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve:

1. You can override the WooCommerce shop page template (archive-product.php) in your theme (or hopefully child theme) to do the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action
2. You can add the functionality you're looking for that's currently hooked into the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action to an action that fires on the Shop page
3. You can create a function that will do the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action, and hook that into an action on the Shop page (similar to option 1, but doesn't override the Shop template - in theory, preventing more work in future if/when WooCommerce updates their templates)

### How to do it

1. Create a folder in your theme/child theme called `woocommerce` and copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` to it and figure out where you want to put the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action. Making sure you're within the `<?php ?>` tags, pop this is where you want: `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );`
2. Find the specific function that does what you're looking for, and add it to an action that's already firing on the Shop page. In the functions.php file of your theme/child theme, (please [use a child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/)), add this within the `<?php ?>` tags:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'specific_function_you_want' );
```

where `'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'` is the first action that fires on the Shop page (you can swap out for another action in `content-product.php` depending on where you want to put the functionality, and `'specific_function_you_want'` is the name of the function currently hooked into the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action that you're looking to replicate.

3. Again, within the `<?php ?>` tags in your functions.php file add the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'do_before_product_summary');

function do_before_product_summary() {

    do_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary');

}
```

### Pros/Cons

1. Easiest and fastest way to do what the question asks; *however*: note that by default, **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** only does two things: display the product image & say if the item is on sale. Both of these are already being shown on the Shop page. Since this method just does the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action, you'll most likely have duplicated content on the Shop page. Probably not the best way to go about this.
2. Gives you the most granularity. I'm making the assumption that you're probably looking to get some specific functionality that is currently hooked to the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action, and do that on the Shop page. If that is the case, this method will allow you do that, without having to worry about any other functionality that's attached to the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action (like duplicated product image as mentioned in method 1). However, you will need to find out where that specific functionality is coming from, which will require a bit of digging.
3. Doesn't require the digging required in method 2, but as with method 1, will do everything that's hooked into the **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** action. The big benefit to using this over method 1 is that when/if WooCommerce updates their templates in the future (as they do from time to time), you won't need to worry about keeping your template override up to date with theirs. This isn't always a big deal, but it is something to keep in mind.